# awk: select text and spend it

Tags: linux, unix, printing, ssh, awk

I try to select `**maniaplanet://#join=suchtbude.elite1@SMStormElite@nadeolabs**` from this text:

```
[2012/09/11 17:39:15] URL: maniaplanet://#join=suchtbude.elite1@SMStormElite@nadeolabs
```

with awk.

This is my Code:

```
LINK=`grep "URL" $SRV_PATH/Logs/ConsoleLog.$PID.txt | awk -F"URL: " '{print $2}'`
echo -e "ManiaLink : [\033[32m$LINK\033[0m] \n"
```

And this is the Output:

```
] niaLink : [maniaplanet://#join=punch.it@SMStormElite@nadeolabs
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Update:

Use field 4, i.e., $4

```
awk '{print $4}'
```

So,

```
echo "[2012/09/11 17:39:15] URL: maniaplanet://#join=suchtbude.elite1@SMStormElite@nadeolabs" | awk '{print $4}'
```

this will give you:

```
maniaplanet://#join=suchtbude.elite1@SMStormElite@nadeolabs
```

I.e., your sequence:

```
$ LINK=`echo "[2012/09/11 17:39:15] URL: maniaplanet://#join=suchtbude.elite1@SMStormElite@nadeolabs" | awk '{print $4}'`

$ echo $LINK
maniaplanet://#join=suchtbude.elite1@SMStormElite@nadeolabs

$ echo -e "ManiaLink : [\033[32m$LINK\033[0m] \n"
ManiaLink : [maniaplanet://#join=suchtbude.elite1@SMStormElite@nadeolabs]
```

**UPDATE**:

This can be simplified by having awk do all of the printing:

```
awk '{printf("ManiaLink : [\033[32m$%s\033[0m] \n", $4)}'`
```

so:

```
LINK=`echo "[2012/09/11 17:39:15] URL: maniaplanet://#join=suchtbude.elite1@SMStormElite@nadeolabs" | awk '{printf("ManiaLink : [\033[32m$%s\033[0m] \n", $4)}'`
```

Comment: same result:

    ] niaLink : [ maniaplanet://#join=punch.it@SMStormElite@nadeolabs

Comment: @PoLLi I guess I'm a bit confused by the problem statement. It looked like you were trying to extract this string from the longer string, which this does. I don't understand the rest purpose of the rest of what you have. Can you clarify?

Comment: ok :) I have a Gameserver and he create a ConsoleLog wiht this text. I try to select this text and give it out like: ManiaLink: [blablabla@blabla] ` LINK=`grep "URL" $SRV_PATH/Logs/ConsoleLog.$PID.txt | awk -F":" '{printf("%s:%s\n", $4, $5)}'` `

Comment: @PoLLi when I try the rest of your sequence I don't have the same problem.

Comment: Try to abstract the relevant parts of all that code. In the meantime I've simplified the solution by having awk do all of the formatting/printing.

Answer (score 0):

If the url is always at the end of the line, you could use this grep regex:

```
grep URL $SRV_PATH/Logs/ConsoleLog.$PID.txt | grep -o '[^ ]*$'
```

Comment: same problem :S ok. here is my Full code: http://pastebin.com/rGZnZVLT  here is my txt file: http://pastebin.com/MKUxvMUw and this is my output: http://pastebin.com/3JkKWuyD